# Chef Tag Node inside ruby_block

Tags: chef-infra

Problem: 
I want to selectively restart a service in chef based on the role of the node. If i don't do a restart i would like to tag the node for for a restart at a later time.

Currently I have some code that looks like this

```
template '/etc/docker/daemon.json' do
  source 'daemon.json.erb'
  mode '0644'
  notifies :run, 'ruby_block[start_right_service]', :immediately
end

ruby_block 'start_right_service' do
  action :nothing
  block do
    if node.role?('dev') ||
       node.role?('desktop')
      Chef::Log.info('Fireing off a restart this node')
      resources(service: 'docker').run_action(:restart)
    else
      Chef::Log.info('Not allowed to restart this node')
      node.run_state['pending_docker_restart'] = true
    end
  end
end
```

So i can't use tag inside the ruby_block as i receive

> undefined method `tag' for Chef::Resource::RubyBlock

I have also tried passing out the variable with node.run_state, but this doesn't seem to work either. any idea's to work around this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

override the [node attribute](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html#recipes) within the `ruby_block`. you can try and do that by replacing `node.run_state` with `node.default`